# apache_request_headers() get specific value with PHP

Tags: php, html, json, php-curl

I do a JSON call and return it With:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
'https://www.example.com/sdfsldfsd3/all-result.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('AccessKey: 
dasdasdq312312qWQEQ'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}  
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now I would like to display the first 5 values of title:

```
string(906287) "{"data":[{"id":12238,"title":"Title no 1"},{"id":7510,"title":"Title no 2"}, 
etc.
```

How am I supposed to display a result like:

```
<a href=page.php?id=12238>Title no 1</a> <br>
<a href=page.php?id=7510>Title no 2</a> <br> etc
```

Thanks in advance

Working code:

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->data as $key => $row) {
    if ($key === 5) break; 
        echo '<a href=page.php?id=' . $row->id . '>' . $row->title . '</a> <br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly have no clue what you're actually trying to do here, or why you're using `apache_request_headers()`. Please include example data (the request) and point out what headers you're trying to use. Then explain what that has to do with "the first 5 values of title".  Are you sending json data in the header?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code does not contain any attempt to print any link markup

Comment: That is correct. If I know how to read the specific value, than the rest is ok for me. PHP skills ok, JSON newbie. :)

Comment: Your question is even more confusing now when you've added a cURL request without _any_ explanation why. Take a step back, edit your question to include a _full_ and _detailed_ explanation of what you need help with. Remove _anything_ that's not directly related to the issue, it just confuses the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You do know that `apache_request_headers()` will return the headers in the request to _your_ server, not the headers from the cURL request? If the question really is "how to use json in PHP", then you can read up on the function [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which decodes a string containing json into proper PHP structures.

Comment: Nope. Tx for the feedback @Magnus

Comment: Remove the `apache_request_headers()` and your `foreach`-loop. Then after the `$json = curl_exec($ch);` line, follow the answer you've gotten below by @pavel and just replace `$str` in that code with your `$json`-variable, like: `$data = json_decode($json);`.

Comment: Tx. Works like a charm! Learned a lot today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to write down all links, use just

```
<?php

$str = '{"data":[{"id":12238,"title":"Title no 1"},{"id":7510,"title":"Title no 2"}]}';
$data = json_decode($str);

foreach ($data->data as $row) {
    echo '<a href=page.php?id=' . $row->id . '>' . $row->title . '</a> <br>';
}
```

If you need just 5 links, `foreach` would be

```
foreach ($data->data as $key => $row) {
    if ($key === 5) break;

    echo '<a href=page.php?id=' . $row->id . '>' . $row->title . '</a> <br>';
}
```